# WPF Binding Combox with different List and different SelectedValue

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, binding, combobox

In my UserControl ucStep2 I have DataContext of Step2InfoData object that has several properties along with :

```
private string rockDensUnit;
public string RockDensity_Unit 
{
    get { return rockDensUnit; }
    set
    {
        if (rockDensUnit != value)
        {
            rockDensUnit = value;
            Changed("RockDensity_Unit");
        }
    }
}
```

In my app I got to bind several combo's with different normally measurement types Like {kg/m3, gm/m3}, {meter, cm} and so on such groups of measures. I mean, multiple combo's to have list of same items. So I preferred to create Class's of such lists that I can use in multiple combos. I created ComboItems.cs which contains all items lists that I will need to populate the drop down.

ComboItems.cs

```
//**OBJECTS I USE FOR LIST OF IEMS** 
// Class for kg, gm
public class KgGmItems
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> KgGmList { get; set; }

    public KgGmItems()
    {
        KgGmList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        KgGmList.Add("kg/m3");
        KgGmList.Add("gram/cm3");
    }

    public string ValueSelected { get; set; }  // Don't know if this is useful in my case
}

// Class for meter, cm
public class MtCmItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MtCmItems()
    {
        Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"meter", "meter"}, 
            {"centimeter", "centimeter"}
        };
    }

    //...
 }
```

XML i.e. ucStep2 View

```
<!-- As the objects KgGmItems doesn't contain in ucStep2.xaml.cs or Step2InfoData (that is bound to this UC) so add reference of those classes -->
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="KgGmObj" ObjectType="{x:Type top:KgGmItems}" />
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MtCmObj" ObjectType="{x:Type top:MtCmItems}" />
</UserControl.Resources>

  <ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource KgGmObj}" ItemsSource="{Binding KgGmList}"  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=RockDensity_Unit, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" 
   Background="#FFB7B39D" Grid.Row="5" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="401,61,0,0" Name="comboBox6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="84" Visibility="Hidden">
  </ComboBox>
```

I want to display ObservableCllection KgGmList items from KgGmItems class and bind the selected value to RockDensity_Unit of class Step2InfoData that is bound to this UserControl.

In the above combo, I am able to display all items in the drop down, also 1st item is selected by default. But the value is not bind to RockDensity_Unit; it's value remains null.

I want this to happen 2-way i.e. when RockDensity_Unit proeprtiy's value is set programmatically, the value should be selected in the drop down. Of course the value should exists in the list.

By default the 1st item should be selected.

**UPDATE**
Added DependencyProperty in ucStep2.xaml.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RockDensityUnitProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("RockDensity_Unit", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl),
     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("kg/m3", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));  

public string RockDensity_Unit
{
    get { return this.GetValue(RockDensityUnitProperty) as string; }
    set { SetValue(RockDensityUnitProperty, value); }
}
```

XML

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource KgGmObj}" ItemsSource="{Binding KgGmList}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=RockDensity_Unit, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ucStep2}}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
   Background="#FFB7B39D" Grid.Row="5" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="401,61,0,0" Name="comboBox6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="84" Visibility="Hidden">
</ComboBox>
```

ERROR

> Error  1  The type reference cannot find a public type named 'ucStep2'. Line 74 Position 194.   This refers to the combobox ", "
>   after FindAncestor

**DOUBT**
The RockDensity_Unit CLR property in Step2InfoData is untouched.

Why is the code not able to find ucStep2 ? FYI, I think this may be relevant :

```
<UserControl x:Class="WellBore.ucStep2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WellBore.Models"
         xmlns:top="clr-namespace:WellBore"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="870" d:DesignWidth="700" MaxHeight="970" MinHeight="700" MaxWidth="600">
```

Comment: FYI, I am using UserControl, I guess that makes difference in using App.xml, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so let's get this binding working... first, I am using an item from your `KgGmItems` class to bind to the `ComboBox`. In this class you have a collection of `string` values to display in the drop down and a `string` property to bind to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem`... perfect! Now I'm assuming that you have an instance of this class in the `Resources` section called `KgGmObj`... let's keep it simple to start with:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource KgGmObj}" ItemsSource="{Binding KgGmList}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding ValueSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

This is all you need to setup the binding between the `ComboBox` and your class. One thing to note though, is that when you try to set the selected item from your code, it will *only* work if you set it to one of the actual items in the collection... I think that this doesn't really count when using `string`s, but it's important to know this anyway. If you were setting a custom class as the type of objects in the `ComboBox` instead, then you could set the selected item like this:

```
ValueSelected = KgGmList.Where(item => item.Name == "NameOfObjectToMatch").Single();
```

Or better like this if you had a uniquely identifiable property:

```
ValueSelected = KgGmList.Where(item => item.Id == Id).Single()
```

With your `string` values, you *should* be able to set the selected item from code like this:

```
ValueSelected = "Some value";
```

UPDATE >>> Ok, so let's have another go... I *think* that I *may* have enough information to go on now. I think that you want something like this:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource KgGmObj}" ItemsSource="{Binding KgGmList}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding RockDensity_Unit, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The problem with this is that you have set the `DataContext` of the `ComboBox` to your `KgGmObj` object. This means that the Framework is going to try to find a property named `RockDensity_Unit` *in that object*. I also see another potential problem in your definition of this property.

In order to bind from a `UserControl` xaml to its code behind, you need to use a `DependencyProperty`. You can find out how to implement these from the [Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) page at MSDN. So first, I would recommend that you implement your `RockDensity_Unit` property as a `DependencyProperty`.

Next, we have to find a way to that property from the `ComboBox` in the xaml... we can do that using a `RelativeSource` binding like this:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource KgGmObj}" ItemsSource="{Binding KgGmList}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding RockDensity_Unit, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=
FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ucStep2}}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Now, if you have a `DependencyProperty` to bind to the `SelectedItem` property and your `UserControl` class is named `ucStep2`, this should all work... let me know how it goes.

UPDATE 2 >>>

Your error is because you have to add an XML namespace at the top of your XAML file... something like this:

```
xmlns:YourNamespace="clr-namespace:ApplicationName.FolderNameContainingClass"
```

Then you use it to reference your class like this:

```
...AncestorType={x:Type YourNamespace:ucStep2} ...
```

Also, in your `DependencyProperty` declaration, you're supposed to supply the name the type of *your* control, not `UserControl`, so change

```
Register("RockDensity_Unit", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl),
```

to

```
Register("RockDensity_Unit", typeof(string), typeof(NameOfYourUserControl),
```

Clearly... replace 'NameOfYourUserControl' with the actual name of your class that extends the `UserControl`.

Comment: Sheridan, The DataContext of the UserControl is Step2InfoData which has a property "RockDensity_Unit. I want to bind the SelectedItem of combobox to RockDensity_Unit. NOTE : KgGmItems class is in other file along with other class's created specially for combo box items. As I need the same list in more than 1 combo & view.

Comment: Is your `ComboBox` inside this `UserControl`? Also, did you say that your property to bind to the `SelectedItem` property is of type `object`? If so, why is that? It shouldn't hurt in this case, but it *should* really be of the same type as the items in the collection. I have to say that I'm somewhat confused by your question... it is missing information. For example, what does this `UserControl` code look like? What is this `Prop` property and where is it declared? What is the relationship between where the `KgGmItems` object and the `UserControl` are declared? Please answer in your question.

Comment: Sheridan, I have edited the whole question with all to the point and clear explainations. Still if any thing is un-clear please let me know. I would be glad to share it.

Comment: Firstly, I got to created the DependencyProperty in ucStep2.xaml.cs. Reg Naming, in Step2InfoData I already have RockDensity_Unit property, I should have the same name in code behind file also. Am I going wrong ? In xml file, I am getting build error "Error 1 The type reference cannot find a public type named 'ucStep2'. Line 74 Position 194. C:\Rameshwar Paswan\Gui_Aug09\Gui\WellBore\UserControl\ucStep2.xaml  This refers to the combobox line & I think this text {x:Type ucStep2} . Chk the code added above.

Comment: Sheridan, 1 more point I would like to clarify - does using this method is not advisable - Is it better to create 2-3 times same ObserableCollection<string> in different views rather than playing with this technique !

Answer (score 1):

Use a Dictionary.

XAML

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Dict}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Value"
          SelectedValuePath="Key"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Prop}"/>
```

Code Behind

```
public Dictionary< ValueType, string > Dict { get; private set; }

private ValueType _prop;
public ValueType Prop
{
    get{ return _prop }
    set
    {
        _prop = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged( "Prop" ); // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}

public ViewModel()
{
    Dict = new Dictionary< ValueType, string >()
    {
         { value1, string1 },
         { value2, string2 },
         { value3, string3 }
    };
}
```

Comment: Wont Dictionary take some space and time as compared to other resources ??  I had read somewhere that Dictionary takes more time comparatively. If nothing works or if my point is inappropriate then have no issue implementing this option too.

Comment: You could probably use a List< Tuple< ValueType, string > > or something like that. I don't know about the space/time considerations of a Dictionary but for something small like a combobox it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: clcto, why do you implement ValueType. I want key also as string. So can I make it as <string, string>. Will that create any problem. I guess if I need key in different dat type like int or so, then that may be helpful. Am  right ?

Comment: Ok, I got this and also got a way to save the selected item to my obj property i.e. getting the DataContext of Combobox and then retrieving the Prop property. Now, when I want to set value from my obj to this combobox, I will have to find the value in Dict keys and set its value to Prop and that will work I guess. Is their any direct way where the seletedValue gets binded to the obj property "Unit" and from obj the value is selected and binded to the combo auto like it works with other controls like DataGrid, TExtBox, Checkbox, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but if you use ObservableCollection, set DisplayMemberPath but leave SelectedValuePath empty then SelectedValue will be set to whole selected item object.

Comment: No, I removed SelectedValuePath from comboBox7. But no success. The value doesn't get store in FractureWidth_Unit. All I am trying for is TwoWay binding with Combobox. The list of items I want from other class that a ObservableCollection<string> property (b'coz I have to use same list in other combos too). And the items selected in the combobox be saved in the Property of object that is the DataContext of the UserControl. That's it.

Comment: @Tvd if you make your ViewModel a INotifyPropertyChanged and call the event PropertyChanged when the value is changed (similar to what I have in the code) then it should automatically update the combobox when the value is changed. And yes, ValueType is any type, including string.

Comment: clcto, please refer the question as I have updated it sticking to one methodology instead of several.